# How to retrieve GCP Stackdriver human readable logs?

Tags: google-cloud-stackdriver, audit-logging

GCP stackdriver logging api provides the log messages in json format. But in the console, under "Home", under the "Activity" tab, it provides the logs in human readable format

`someone@gmail.com has retrieved data from BigQuery table bq_table_name`

Is there a way to get these Human readable logs instead of the complete JSON log messages?

[image: From the official documentation]

Comment: I can read JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no way to get the templated message for audit logs provided by http://console.cloud.google.com/home/activity apart from the UI itself.